# Nombres standard de ejercicios fisicos de gimnasio

Tags: gym

**English**
I asked the same question in English and got useful answers. I would like to know if the names and terms used are any different for Spanish-speaking countries. As with my prior question, is their a standardized set of names and terms for exercises that I can refer to?

**Spanish**
He hecho la misma pregunta en ingles y obtuve respuestas muy útiles. Mi duda es: voy al gimnasio a hacer musculación, y hago mas de 30 ejercicios diferentes como parte de una rutina de 5 dias. Es dificil aprenderlos y recordarlos de memoria, y estoy pidiendo por un recurso oficial o standard en español que diga los nombres mas comunes empleados para cada actividad. Se que pueden variar segun gimnasio, pero posiblemente existan algunas convenciones y algunos acuerdoa generales, un mismo ejercicio posria tener 2 nombres pero no cualquier nombre. Que es dominada por ejemplo?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange

I feel like, at the least, it would be good to have a translation in English stating that the Spanish names are being requested.

Answer (score 1):

This is the answer from the question you asked in englisch before... why do you ask the same one in spanish? 
Google translate:
Es fácil confundirse, pero la mayoría de los ejercicios tienen nombres muy descriptivos, y algunos de ellos cubrir clases enteras de ejercicios.

El quid de la cuestión

Pulsando significa que estés pulsando / empujando algo lejos de usted, como press de banca o press de hombros.

Note una vez más que las otras palabras son bastante descriptiva también. "Banco" y "gastos generales", ambos ayudan a describir el movimiento.

Tirar o remo significa que usted está tirando algo para usted, como pull-ups y pull-downs, así como filas de cable, filas verticales, filas dumbell etc.

Las extensiones son ejercicios donde ampliarse por ambos brazos o piernas contra una resistencia. Ejemplos aquí son extensiones de tríceps por cable y extensiones de la pierna. Usted encontrará máquinas de extensión de la pierna en la mayoría de los gimnasios, así como equipos de cable. Lo sabrás cuando lo veas.

Rizos son lo contrario de las extensiones. Aquí, se cierra la articulación del codo o la rodilla contra resistencia. Ejemplos de ello son flexiones de bíceps y doblar las piernas. El primero viene en gran variedad.

Moderadores

Hay un gran número de movimientos para todas las clases mencionadas, pero de nuevo, la mayoría de ellos tienen nombres muy descriptivos.

Tomemos por ejemplo el press de banca inclinado. Aquí estamos, obviamente, utilizando un banco, que se inclinaba un poco, por lo que estamos más vertical (henceincline). Y estamos de nuevo presionando algo. Pero no dice lo que estás presionando, por lo que podría ser una barra o un par de mancuernas. Así que si alguien dice "vamos a hacer press de banca inclinado", es perfectamente natural preguntarse "barra o mancuernas?".

Así que un nombre aún mejor sería inclinar press de pecho con barra, pero te acostumbrarás a una gran cantidad de estos cortos-manos.

Nombres independientes

Una gran cantidad de ejercicios tienen sus propios nombres, simplemente porque describirlos sería demasiado tiempo para llamar a un nombre.

Tomemos por ejemplo el Trituracráneos que tendría que ser nombrado banco cerca extensiones de tríceps con barra agarre planas para ser descriptivo. (Por supuesto, algunas de estas palabras están abiertos para el cambio en función de la persona que lo hace.)

Nadie va a pensar menos de ti por preguntar qué es exactamente un "press francés" o un "rizo concentrada" es. Pero sabed esto, puedes ver videos de cualquier ejercicio simplemente googlear el nombre como lo oyes.

De hecho, te sugiero que hagas esto para la mayoría de los ejercicios que he mencionado en esta respuesta.

Kudos to the original author in english!

Comment: Tu traduccion no me sirve de nada pues entiendo inglés. Tradujiste varias palabras muy raro, usaste un traductor automatico como el de Google? Justamente hice esta pregunta para saber nombres que se USAN en español. La traduccion que hiciste tiene nombres que nunca escuche como: curl por rizos?, corto-manos? Claramente usaste un traductor automatico. Te agradeceria que borres tu respuesta, es contraproducente.

Comment: If you understand english why do you comment  and ask in spanish?  I wrote that it is a google translation. To me this is a duplicate question.

Comment: Because spanish speaking countries have different cultures, and name different objects or actions in ways that can't be translated in a word by word fashion. I need to know if spanish speaking countries there are other conventions for naming. My routine sheet is written in spanish.